# ER Model for Quiz game

Tags: sql, sql-server, .net-core, entity-relationship, er-modeling

I'm trying to create ER Model for the Quiz game and I need help.
What is the best solution for tracking user answers in the specific game?

What do you think about putting it in GamesByUser table (GamesByUser would have a `List<QuestionOption>` )

ER Model without tracking user answers:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You ask them a question...  then they give an answer.. those things seem pretty directly relate so I would related them to the 'game' in an equivalent way.

```
Game
 - GameQuestion
     - GameAnswer
          *GameID
          *PlayerID
          *QuestionID
           OptionID

* = Key
```